# How to validate an amp READER_ID?

Tags: amp-html

When using Google AMP pages, we provide a login page. In this login page, we link the logged user with the READER_ID provided by Google, and it thus become a unique key of the user.

This key is then used by AMP to retrieve some informations about the user, including some profile datas.

The problem is that we let an external actor choose a unique key for our users, via a public login page. How can we certify that a READER_ID is generated by Google? Does they furnish an API to verify a READER_ID validity, or can we use a public key provided by Google?

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way to verify the READER_ID. However, you don't need to use the READER_ID as a user id. Instead, you can generate and use your own id once the user signs-in/signs-up. The READER_ID is only needed in cases where you don't want to create a user account (e.g. paywalls offering a limited number of free articles).

Comment: OK but if I undersand correctly, AMP choose to show the paywall by calling the WS we defined, and the only parameter that he can use to identify the user is the READER_ID.

Or can we send a unique ID or a token to AMP when the login is done?

Comment: You are completely in control of the data (it's just JSON) that is send to the page. You can completely ignore the READER_ID if you want.

Comment: I will investigate if we can say to AMP to show the paywall without using READER_ID. The doc is more about tracking users…